# What does "a path up and to the right for stocks" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm currently reading [**this article,**](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/three-pillars-of-bull-market-in-place-morning-brief-095329123.html) which has this line:

> Of course, in hindsight it is always easier to say that some new development turned out to be nothing. And so Thursday's market's decline is absolutely worth noting: we will only know with hindsight whether this was the beginning of a rocky period for stocks or just another hiccup along **a path up and to the right for stocks**.

There are too many definitions from dictionaries to mention here.

Googling "to the right for meaning" did not produce anything useful.

How I should interpret this expression?

Comment: You should have some idea of what stock market price charts actually ***look like*** if you're gonna read about them in the financial pages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know there are actually quite few up and to the right for stocks. By the way, close vote? Is he/she serious?

Comment: Yes, I'm serious. The meanings of "up" and "to the right" are straightforward, and the *relevance* of those adverbs in the context of ***stock market** [charts]* is equally obvious. The question is thus primarily about finance / investment, not "learning English".

Comment: @FumbleFingers The potential students that could take your class would wonder how much limited and strict they can ask **about English** and start considering to choose another teachers..

Comment: Well, you've got your answer. I just don't see how knowing this highly context-specific usage would help anyone who *wasn't* trying to understand its relevance to financial charts. And I don't want to seem insulting, but ***in context*** the meaning seems trivially obvious to me if you've ever seen a financial chart.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't want to argue anymore so I will leave but I thought you are a quite decent man.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you either. I wouldn't have closevoted unless I could see that someone else had already given you your answer (or I'd have given the answer myself while closevoting, And unlike *some* users here, I wouldn't ***downvote*** questions like this (which would "cost" you reputation points, thereby limiting your ability to use the site). Also note that I'm only one person, and it needs ***five*** ordinary users to closevote, so my action won't have any effect (apart from annoying you) unless four other people agree with me. I won't retract, but I am sorry you're unhappy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you misunderstood what the OP's question is about. The point is that the phrase "up and to the right" is an adjective describing the *path*, not the *stocks*. The OP seems to have parsed the sentence as "[the path up] and [to the right for stocks]" not "[the path [up and to the right]] [for stocks]".

Comment: @alephzero: You're right that I had not understood things like that, and I can see that the ***highlighting*** in the question supports that perspective. But it seems to me that would presuppose OP wouldn't have had a problem if the text had talked about *just another hiccup along **a path up*** [or ***an upward path***] *for stocks*. And if anyone can understand the metaphorical significance of ***up*** on such charts/paths, I don't see why ***to the right*** for the other axis should present a problem.

Comment: @alephzero Ah thank you. Still at now, I thought "up and to the right" was referring "for stocks". Great. Thank you.

Comment: In English, your “… path up and to the right for (anything)…” means only what its context suggests.

Can you explain your “… path up and to the right for (anything)…”?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin That's what I asked in this question :).

Comment: @Kentaro Then can you explain it two or three other ways?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin May be for example, "He had his life with his path up and to the right for the salary" or "As a musician, he spent his whole life with his fame up and to the right during entire life"?

Comment: @Kentaro Either that is wholly off topic, or you've hit the nail right on the head… Nothing in English may ever be, for example, "He had his life with his path up and to the right for (anything, ever)" or "As a musician, he spent his whole life with his fame up and to the right during entire life"

Would you rather rop the whole thing, or find several better translations… say, three or four?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin First of all I don't understand what to rop is. I'm losing your focus btw.

Comment: Sorry… I meant "drop…". Finally, I suspect the closest we come to using an expression like that in general English is the somewhat similar "a steep learning curve", which seems in the process of being debased by having the crucial "steep" stripped away. 

Oh… and "ramp up…" and in all three cases, the major problem is that the time-line means "to the right" is a given. How could the plot move left?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Graphs of stock prices over time show time from left to **right** and value from bottom to top.

[image]

A stock that's increasing in value is graphed as a line moving **up and to the right**.

Answer (score 7):

Most graphs that show the price of stocks and shares have "time" on the horizontal axis and price on the vertical axis.  And so they tend to look like:

```
|   ___    /\
|  /   \  /  \  /
| /     \/    \/
|/
|____________________
      time
```

If the price is increase as time passes,  then the line will tend to go `/`  which is "up and to the right". It is a description of a line with a positive gradient.