# "to rop something"

Tags: word-meaning

[**A user repetitively has been asking for the another versions using the phrase
"up and to the right for",**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/278284/what-does-a-path-up-and-to-the-right-for-stocks-mean) in that process, I encountered a verb that no dictionary
records and no googing helps. What does to rop something mean?

User's message

> Kentaro Either that is wholly off topic, or you've hit the nail right on the head… Nothing in English may ever be, for example, "He had his life with his path up and to the right for (anything, ever)" or "As a musician, he spent his whole life with his fame up and to the right during entire life" **Would you rather rop the whole thing,** or find several better translations… say, three or four?

What does the verb mean?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ironically, I also see a verb in your question that no dictionary records.  What does "no **googing** helps" mean? (I know,  it's a typo for "googling" just thought it was a funny coincidence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo. The intended word was almost certainly "drop".

"Drop the whole thing" means to stop discussing some topic.